# JQuery Change class in nearest "i" of the Div Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few Div's with an onclick function as below:

```
<div onclick="myfunc();">
    <i class="myclass1"></i>
</div>

<div onclick="myfunc();">
    <i class="myclass1"></i>
</div>

<div onclick="myfunc();">
    <i class="myclass1"></i>
</div>

<div onclick="myfunc();">
    <i class="myclass1"></i>
</div>
```

I want to change the class in the "i" of the Div I decide click.

This is what I'm trying but nothing is changing:

```
$(this).closest('i').removeClass('myclass1');
$(this).closest('i').addClass('myclass2');
```

How can I fix this issue so it changes the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid inline handlers, and you need to `.find` that `i` inside `div`. `.closest()` search up the `dom`

```
$('div').on('click',function(){

  $(this).find('i').removeClass('myclass1');
  $(this).find('i').addClass('myclass2');
});
```

Comment: Note that you could simplify this further down to just `$(this).find('i').toggleClass('myclass1 myclass2');`

Comment: This one is changing all the div classes, not just the one I clicked on

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsbin.com/hudama/edit?html,css,js,output   It is good practice to avoid inline handlers, and add those div's you want to change some class, but if not, you can insert this into `myfunc()`

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would put the click event on the i element instead:

```
$('.myclass1').click(function(){  
$(this).removeClass('myclass1');
$(this).addClass('myclass2');
 })

$('.myclass2').click(function(){  
$(this).removeClass('myclass2');
$(this).addClass('myclass1');
 })
```

The i html element is really meant for defining italics http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp

Comment: Yes I know but it's also highly used for icons :)